# What is the term for an object that can produce events?

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

I have two generic collections in my code, EventableCollection and EventableSortedList - which are basically collection classes that provide Adding, Added, Inserting, Inserted etc. as events, in plain and sorted varieties respectively. However FxCop tells me that I should correct the spelling of Eventable. Which is fair enough, seeing as it's a made up word.

However, I'm struggling with coming up with a better name for those classes. I don't want to use Observable because I don't want to clash with the 4.0 framework type. So - does anyone have any ideas? Or can I just suppress the warning and move on with my life?

Comment: How about Collection<Event>, SortedList<Event> ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're meaning there?

Comment: I mean, why don't you use generics which would help you indicate the "contained" type while keeping a common name for the collection?

Comment: Aha, now I re-read your question twice and figured you are meaning to indicate that the collection class can raise events, not contain events...therefore my comments are irrelevant. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very good at English, but what about `Notifiable`?

Comment: I'm marking this as correct because it was 50/50 between Notifiable and Subscribable, but apparently Subscribable isn't a word either :)

Comment: @MattWhitfield, FxCop [should update it's vocabulary](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=Subscribable&use1913=on) =P.

Answer (score 1):

How does `HookableCollection`, `SubscribableCollection` or `BroadcastingCollection` sound?

Answer (score 0):

I would still use the word **Observable** and be done with it. Use a namespace to avoid a clash with the Microsoft classes (that's what namespaces are for!).

This definitely makes the most sense seeing as events are an implementation of the observer pattern.